# Python load testing socket communication

Tags: python, benchmarking

I have this two Python script server.py and client.py which connects using socket, server just looks like:

```
while True:
    try:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        handle(conn, addr)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

So it just handles one client at a time then later I'll add gevent so it can handle clients concurrently.

How do I benchmark this to determine client request/second with vs without gevent?

I found a lot of HTTP base benchmarking tool but what about TCP? Ideally I'd like the test to run several of my client.py script and use that as a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing my own threaded benchmarking test.